# Archivos .csv idénticos, pero con tamaños diferentes

Tags: csv

Tengo dos sistemas programados en lenguajes diferentes que generan un CSV en función a una determinada vista de la base de datos.

Ambos generan el archivo .csv correctamente, con la cantidad de columnas y filas que deberían (3063 filas por 16 columnas). Tanto la información como el formato de los campos es el mismo. Pero uno de los .csv pesa 487 kb. y el otro 630 kb.

¿Cuál podría ser el motivo por el que un archivo .csv con la misma información, sea más pesado que el otro?

Comment: Influye la codificación del archivo y el tamaño del bloque del sistema de archivos.